# Explain this behaviour of ant task?

Tags: ant, weblogic, weblogic12c

Any `<taskdef>` which i refer from `weblogic_home/server/lib` resolves the class. If I copy lib folder out from wl_home and refer in `<taskdef>` which actually does not resolve the class.

I decompiled weblogic.jar but it has nothing.

Any reason behind this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

older version than WLS 10.0 could use weblogic.jar as a provider of some WLS classes, however now with WLS 12c, it is only a relative reference in its manifest classpath (pointing to other jar files in the WLS installation).

Therefore, it cannot be moved, otherwise, the references will be broken.

It can be checked at `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62846539/how-to-acheive-servicegen-behavior-in-jwsc-task - Can you please give suggestions on this?